# Angular 2 Production build file is large

Tags: angular

I have just created a new angular app using "ng new appName" and put in some buttons (from ng-bootstrap). I wanted to try to deploy to aws to check it out. However, when I run ng build --prod, the one of the dist file (vendor.a9e57aafdd6abc88b94a.bundle.map) generated is 7.7mb. Here is a screen shot of the files. What is the best way to resolve this issue so the user does not have to download that big of a file upon load?

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Huge number of files generated for every AngularJS 2 project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38718690/huge-number-of-files-generated-for-every-angularjs-2-project)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I dont have alot of files though. The dist folder only has a few

Comment: Actually you don't need map files. You can change file list with angular-cli.json file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are showing the file size of a `.map` file. A mapping file is used to let for instance the browser development tools map your compiled javascript to separate typescript files, which makes debugging easier. You've build this with a slightly older version of `angular-cli`. If you do not want these sourcemaps just build with a `--no-sourcemap` option, or upgrade to the latest version, where `--prod` will automatically disable sourcemapping. This will also greatly increase build times.

For a production build you only need your `index.html`, the `css` and `js` files, and your assets folder (+ favicon). If you manage to set up your webserver even better to serve static gzip files, you can even just place the `js.gz` and `css.gz` files on your webserver, and these will be served, which will increase performance even more.

Your users will not download a `sourcemap` file, unless you place it there, and they open up their browser console. This will give them insight in how you build your app. This can be unwanted

Comment: I didn't realise that .map file is not required. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

How To Keep Angular Deployment Size Small :

Take a look at the structure of my [project](https://github.com/younos1986/HowToKeepAngularDeploymentSizeSmall) .

Home page size is 922kb . [demo](https://younos1986.github.io/)