# Run angular7 application from legacy web application

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular7-router

I have built a new Angular7 application and locally angular application is working fine. 
Now I need to launch my angular application from the existing legacy web application which is build on Java/JSP.
In the existing legacy application, I have a URL. On click of that URL, angular application should open.

But whenever I am hitting the URL, seems like routing is not happening properly to angular app.

Local angular application is running successfully on - http://localhost:4200/alerts;alerttype=renewals;cor=411119

What I did so far,
I have copied the angular dist folder to the webcontent folder of legacy application and running the application as below

http://localhost:9086/customer/eWeb/AlertApp/alerts;alerttype=renewals;cor=411119

app.routing.module.ts

```
    const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'alerts', component: AlertsComponent },
    { path: 'customer/eWeb/AlertApp/alerts', component: AlertsComponent 
     },
    ];
```

Can anyone help and tell how to launch the angular application from the legacy application? what all routing needs to be configured?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Once you build your angular application, you get a few js and css files (depending upon your code, mode details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38718690/huge-number-of-files-generated-for-every-angular-project))

Just bundle and move these files on the server and call the main file (bundle.js) on a JSP page.

Before doing this, don't forget to set the base path in index.html

Comment: so in my case, base path in index.html is as <base href="/">  Do you want to add something else? Also I do not see main bundle.js file after build

Answer (score 1):

Update your server-side url config (SpringMVC or SpringBoot config or Servlet web.xml) to return your parent jsp.

http://localhost:9086/customer/eWeb/AlertApp --> app.jsp

In app.jsp, just include css + bundled js files (similar your angular index.html)

```
<body>
 <div app> </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```